# elasticsearch sorting unexpected null returned

Tags: elasticsearch

I followed the doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-fields.html to add sorting column for **name** field. Unfortunately, it is not working

These are the steps:

1. add index mapping

> ```
> PUT /staff
> {
>     "mappings": {
>         "staff": {
>             "properties": {
>                 "id": {
>                     "type":   "string",
>                     "index":  "not_analyzed"
>                 },
>                 "name": { 
>                     "type":     "string",
>                     "fields": {
>                         "raw": { 
>                             "type":  "string",
>                             "index": "not_analyzed"
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

2. Add document

> ```
> POST /staff/list {
>         "id": 5,
>         "name": "abc" 
>     }
> ```

3. Search for the **name.raw**

> ```
> POST /staff_change/_search
> {
>     "sort": "name.raw"
> }
> ```

However, the sort field in the response return **null**

```
"_source": {
       "id": 5,
        "name": "abc"
    },
    "sort": [
        null
    ]
  }
```

I dont know why it is not working and I cant search relevant issue doc related this. Does someone come across this issue

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mappings are incorrect. You create a mapping `staff` inside index `staff` and then index documents under mapping `list` inside index `staff` which works but with a dynamic mapping, not the one you added. In the end you are searching for all the documents in the index `staff`. Try this:

```
PUT /staff
{
    "mappings": {
        "list": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type":   "string",
                    "index":  "not_analyzed"
                },
                "name": { 
                    "type":     "string",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": { 
                            "type":  "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then index:

```
POST /staff/list {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "abc aa" 
}
```

And query:

```
POST /staff/list/_search
{
    "sort": "name.raw"
}
```

Results in:

```
"hits": [
    {
        "sort": [
           "abc aa"
        ]
     }
...
```